# Highlighting only in a certain file

Tags: highlight

At every opening of a special file I want vim to automatically highlight all the lines, where the 7th character is a `1`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you probably want to create your own syntax file, you can read [`:h mysyntaxfile`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile) for more details

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/syntax
```

Then you want to define your own filetype for the file you are editing, you could do that with a modeline ([`:h modeline`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#modeline)) e.g. adding this line as the first or last line of your file:

```
vim: ft=myownfiletype
```

If the file already has a filetype you can set several ones, for example if this is a C file:

```
//vim: ft=c.myownfiletype
```

If you can't add a modeline to your file you can use other ways to define a file type (see [`:h ftdetect`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#ftdetect) or [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Filetype.vim))

Then you need to create the syntax file for this new filetype (see [`:h :syn-files`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3asyn-files)):

```
$ touch ~/.vim/syntax/myownfiletype.vim
```

Finally in this file you can put your commands, a basic example would be:

```
syntax match Error /^.\{6}1/
```

Which means:

- `syntax match` create a new highlighting for line which will match what follows ([`:h :syn-match`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3asyn-match))
- `Error` Use the `Error` highlighting group. Note that you could use another one or define your own one (see [`:h highlight-groups`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#highlight-groups))
- `/^.\{6}1/` match the lines beginning (`^`) with 6 characters `.\{6}` followed by `1`

Comment: Despite the missing ^ this highlights only the beginning of the line.

Comment: @quiliup `/^.\{6}1.*/` maybe?

Comment: yes, thank you! The next problem in your answer is that this affects all c-files. How does the highlighting only affect the certain file (/path/to/file)? I also need to type `set syntax=c` in Ex mode currently, since the file isn't a c-file. How can this be run automatically?

Comment: @quiliup I misread your question, I edited the answer to match your need :)

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I want. Thank you very much!